# com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Can't instantiate class: com.b2c.web.beans.hotel.HotelSearchResultsBean

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

**How can I find out from which place exception is throwing?**

> com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Can't instantiate class: com.b2c.web.beans.hotel.HotelSearchResultsBean.

Sample stack trace

```
       com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance (Unknown Source)

                 com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build (Unknown Source)

         com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush (Unknown Source)

                com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create (Unknown Source)

     com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean (Unknown Source)

        com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue (Unknown Source)

    com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue (Unknown Source)

     com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue (Unknown Source)

               com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue (AstIdentifier.java:116)

                     com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase (AstValue.java:151)

                    com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue (AstValue.java:200)

                com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue (ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)

         org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue (WeldValueExpression.java:50)

         org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue (WeldValueExpression.java:50)

….sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.writeText (Unknown Source)

…sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.writeText (Unknown Source)

  com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextInstruction.write (Unknown Source)

…sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin (Unknown Source)

       com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll (Unknown Source)

            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll (Unknown Source)

            javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll (Unknown Source)

…pplication.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView (Unknown Source)

…sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView (Unknown Source)

org.ocpsoft.rewrite.faces.RewriteViewHandler.renderView (RewriteViewHandler.java:186)

  javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView (Unknown Source)

  javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView (Unknown Source)

  javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView (Unknown Source)

    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute (Unknown Source)

                  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase (Unknown Source)

           com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render (Unknown Source)

                javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service (Unknown Source)

…undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest (ServletHandler.java:85)

…ervlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter (FilterHandler.java:130)

     org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter (RewriteFilter.java:205)

        io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter (ManagedFilter.java:60)

…ervlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter (FilterHandler.java:132)

….undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest (FilterHandler.java:85)

…lers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest (ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)

…rvlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest (ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

…curity.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest (SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)

…ndertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest (PredicateHandler.java:43)

…ecurity.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest (SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)

…ecurity.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest (ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)

…ndertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest (PredicateHandler.java:43)

….handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest (AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)

….ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest (ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)

…handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest (AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)

…curity.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest (CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)

…security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest (SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)

…ndertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest (PredicateHandler.java:43)

…ertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest (JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

…ndertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest (PredicateHandler.java:43)

…ndertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest (PredicateHandler.java:43)

…vlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest (ServletInitialHandler.java:261)

…servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest (ServletInitialHandler.java:247)

…rtow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000 (ServletInitialHandler.java:76)

…servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest (ServletInitialHandler.java:166)

       io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler (Connectors.java:197)

            io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run (HttpServerExchange.java:764)

      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

                                   java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)


caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Once you're capable to ask "Why is variable X here null?" instead of "Why do I get a NullPointerException?", feel free to ask a new question with sufficient detail about variable X so anyone else in the world can reproduce your problem in a scratchpad project.

Comment: Thanks for reply,  I'm getting this details only in my server log. and not getting any line number or name of the file. For remaining errors i'm getting line number and all. some times facing this like exceptions and stucking. Any way to find with this details?

Comment: Remove the badly configured custom logger / exceptionhandler, then look once again in server log. If you have no idea how then leave it (for now) and just put a debug breakpoint in bean's constructor to figure out variable X.

Comment: Why is the lines in the stack-trace right-aligned? Arabic?